# Yii2 console writing files to the uploads directory

Tags: php, yii2

Am using yii2 console with faker and this is what i have in the migrations code

```
 public function safeUp()
{
    $faker = Faker\Factory::create();
    for( $i= 0; $i<20; $i++){
        $this->insert('tbl_user',array(
            'username' =>$faker->userName,
            'password_hash' => \Yii::$app->security->generatePasswordHash(5378),
            'email'=>$faker->email ,
            'status'=>10,
            'auth_key'=>Yii::$app->security->generateRandomString(),
            'created_at'=>$faker->unixTime($max = 'now'),
            'updated_at'=>$faker->unixTime($max = 'now'),
            'profile_pic'=>$faker->image(Yii::getAlias("uploads"), $width = 640, $height = 480, 'cats', false)

        ));
    }

}
```

THe problem comes in the profile_pic part and it always throws an error of

```
Cannot write to directory "uploads"
```

I have added both read and write permissions to the folder uploads butstill it fails

bychecking the permissions via `ls -ld uploads` it returns

```
drwxrwxrwx 3   //shows the read write and even execute permissions are set
```

What could be wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Alias argument should have "@" sign

Answer (score 1):

If your uploads directory is in the base path of the application, the code should look like the following:

```
...
    'profile_pic'=>$faker->image(Yii::getAlias('@web/path_to/uploads'), $width = 640, $height = 480, 'cats', false)
...
```

You should adjust the alias to wherever your uploads directory is.
In the above example '@web' refers to the base URL of the currently running Web application. Here is a list of predefined aliases you can use: http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-concept-aliases.html#predefined-aliases

And here is more information about resolving aliases: http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-concept-aliases.html#resolving-aliases

Comment: by digging deeper into faker ive found out that supplying the alias only tyhe string is passed and the faker ( vendor package) that stores the image checks to see if its a directory which fails hence throws the error, Ive endend up modifying the vendor function to include the full root path rather than the string version of the passed alias